# Trying to write multiple choice quiz in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write a multiple choice quiz using RoR. I'm a beginner so any help is appreciated. So far, I have a Quizzes controller containing the following code:

```
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController


def new
    @quiz = Quiz.new
end

def create
    @quiz = Quiz.new(quiz_params)
    if @quiz.save
        redirect_to "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
    end
end

def quiz_params
    params.require(:quiz).permit(:question, :wrong_answer_1,
                                :wrong_answer_2,
                                :wrong_answer_3,
                                :correct_answer)
end

def show
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

My quiz has five columns (excluding ID) - question, wrong_answer_1, wrong_answer_2, wrong_answer_3, and correct_answer. I'm pretty sure my database/migrations are correct.

I'm really not sure where to go from here. I want the user to have the ability to select, using radio buttons, the correct_answer and the screen to say correct and vice versa with wrong_answer_1, wrong_answer_2, etc.

Comment: Is answer a model in you rails app?

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the app to include anwser as a model. Then each question could `has_many` answers, and one correct answer.   the You should use the [radio_button_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag)

#### _show_question.html.erb

```
<% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
  <li>
    <%= radio_button_tag("answer[#{question.id}]", answer.id) %>
    <%= label("answer_".concat(answer.id.to_s).to_sym, answer.content) %>
 </li>
<% end %>
```

#### app/models/question.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: questions
# ...
#  correct_answer_id :integer
# ...
has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
```

#### app/models/answer.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: answers
# ...
#  question_id :integer
# ...
belongs_to :question
```

#### app/controllers/quizzes_controller.rb

```
def show
  @quiz.includes(:answers).find_by(params[:id]) 
end
```

Comment: So would you have a Quiz/Question model that contains just one column (the question)? And then have another model that contains four columns: wrong answers 1, 2, and 3 and the correct answer?

Comment: In the answer model you would have a question_id key that maps back the question it is related to. I've updated the answered to question to reflect this.

Comment: Hi Antarr, appreciate the help. What would you put in the controller? And additionally, would you have one Quizzes controller and then two models: the question and answer?

Answer (score 0):

you already have a new, so you can create questions with fake answers alraedy right.
now you can create a def index, that will display all your questions.

so do:

```
def index
 @questions = Question.all
end
```

in your index.html.erb file
do something along the lines of:
@questions.each do |q|...
and display them like q.wronganswer, q.wrongaswer2, etc.
you have to figure out a way to display at random the answer options, otherwise they'll all have the same format of
Question
Wrong Answer
Wrong Answer 2
Wrong Answer 3
Correct Answer